# pdfkit is crushing exe from pyinstaller

Tags: python, html, pdf, pyinstaller, pdfkit

I have this project in which I convert HTML files I create to PDF. Basically I create two HTML files, merge them into a single HTML file, and I convert this file with `pdfkit`.
When I run my code in `Spyder` everything is fine, I get this message in the terminal:

```
Loading pages (1/6)
Counting pages (2/6)                                               
Resolving links (4/6)                                                       
Loading headers and footers (5/6)                                           
Printing pages (6/6)
Done
```

and I get my desired PDF files, and I can also see the three HTML files (the two I create and the merged one) and also some pictures I save from my GUI and attach to my HTML/PDF files.

So far so good, but when I convert my code with `pyinstaller` it crushes on the PDF conversation.. I use this line to convert my HTML to PDF:

```
pdfkit.from_file(fileAddress_final,fileAddress_PDF)
```

where  `fileAddress_final` is the merged HTML file, and `fileAddress_PDF` is the desired path to where the PDF file would be saved.

When I tried to run an `.exe` file without the line above, it did not crush (but obviously does not create the PDF file I wish).

I tried to find an answer to it before, but I might have not been clear enough, and also ran some tests, so I managed to find out that this is the only line that causes problems.

Did anyone experience this kind of thing as well? Any ideas of how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how I can silence the output, I just simply had to add this:

```
options = {
           'quiet': ''
          }
pdfkit.from_file(fileAddress_final,fileAddress_PDF,options=options)
```

And this stopped the output, and prevented from my GUI to crash.